# Is this an error to omit version specification in Maven dependency tag?

Tags: maven, tags, dependencies, version

Why didn't they type version specifications here in the sample about hibernate: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html

(Section 1.1.1)

In which circumstances Maven can work without version tag inside dependency tag?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the version is specified in a parent Pom, so it's not required in the child Pom, but it must be specified somewhere in the hierarchy of poms.